# Spring framework springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient connection error handling

Tags: java

I am trying to handle exceptions when a POST is done via @FeignClient

What I would like to do is to catch and log if there is a connection problem, for example if a provider that I am connecting is down and cannot reachable. I tried to catch it with **java.net.ConnectException**

but I got this compilation error which makes sense

**Error:(113, 11) java: exception java.net.ConnectException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement**

So my question is, is there any way to handle this specific exception when the feign client is not reachable, so I can log it as connection problem.

My FeignClient interface

```
public interface PluginFeignClient {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/prepare", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Map<String, Object> createPrepare(@RequestBody CreatePluginPrepareRequest request);
}
```

Service that calls feign client

```
try {
            PluginFeignClient resource = commsService.buildServicerPluginClient(servicer.getName(), PluginFeignClient.class, applicationId, originatingIpAddress);
            Map<String, Object> response = resource.createPrepare(pluginRequest);
            prepareResponse = new PrepareResponse(response);
        } catch (WpbCommunicationException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("ComId={}, PayId={}: Exception building Stripe resource", storedPayment.getCompanyId(),
                    storedPayment.getPaymentId(), e);
            throw e;
        } catch (FeignException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("ComId={}, PayId={}: Got FeignException calling plugin", storedPayment.getCompanyId(),
                    storedPayment.getPaymentId(), e);
            if (e.status() == 400) {
                throw new InvalidDataException(e.getMessage());
            }
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("ComId={}, PayId={}: Unknown error calling plugin", storedPayment.getCompanyId(),
                    storedPayment.getPaymentId(), e);
            throw e;
        }
```

So the question is I would like to add another catch to the service to handle connection exceptions. Any idea about what kind of exception feign client is throwing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do implementing your own `errorDecoder class` and creating a custom exception for the `feignClient`.

Here is a little example to achieve it:

[Feign Error Handling](http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/feign-error-handling-with-errordecoder/)

In case of error `errorDecoder` will be triggered before finishing the transaction and you can handle the exception the way you like.